# How can I load bash (as opposed to sh) in org babel to enable #+BEGIN_SRC bash?

Tags: bash, org-mode, org-babel

I see references to, and examples that use

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash
```

But in my org mode version (elpa, org 20150316) in the menu of `customize-variable org-babel-load-languages`, there is no "bash" item, only shell. Attempting to evaluate code such as

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash
ls -l
#+END_SRC
```

I get

> org-babel-execute-src-block: No org-babel-execute function for bash!

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought, but could you try `#+begin_src sh :shebang "#!/bin/bash"`?

Comment: This works for the example I gave, so I should accept it if you make your comment into answer. Although my original purpose was to use some of the ability to process associative arrays [discussed here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/84282) which the `:shebang' solution does not provide. I think all this points to the _ob-sh.el_ , part of org on melpa, does not have some patches I expected.

Comment: The problem is both melpa and elpa have an older version of _ob-sh.el_ which does not have the bash changes. The version on [org git](git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git) does have a version _ob-shell.el_ with bash enabled. Requiring/loading this version in my init.el, something like `(load-file "~/org-git/org-mode/lisp/ob-shell.el")` allows `#+BEGIN_SRC bash` and also allows org babel processing of associative arrays.

Comment: Yes, `ob-shell.el`  is the key.

Answer (score 29):

For me, I did

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

as shown on http://orgmode.org/elpa.html to make sure I had the latest Org version (vanilla Emacs ships with its own version of Org). Then I installed the `org` package interactively after doing `M-x list-packages`. Then I could do

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages
    '(
        (shell . t)
    )
)
```

which allows `#+BEGIN_SRC bash`.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, one adds the org-babel-do-load-languages code snippet into your .emacs file.

Answer (score 6):

It seems `bash` is covered by the `shell` identifier.

Therefore, you have to activate insert “Shell Script” in `customize-variable org-babel-load-languages`.

Tested version: 20150810 from MELPA.

Answer (score 5):

See the value of `org-babel-sh-command` (which defaults to "sh"), and only use "sh" as the language.

Comment: I already set to `bash` in my _init.el_. I think the problem is that the ob-sh.el, part of org on melpa (I am using melpa, not elpa as I stated) has no mention of `bash`. Perhaps that means it does not have some patches, I need to look into it further and maybe get a later version...

Comment: After cheking, it seems the above var disappeared from Git Org. It seems to have been replaced by `org-babel-shell-names`. Maybe putting "bash" as the first component of it? ... if it does exist in your Org version?

Comment: What version of org-babel are you using? The problem is even the most recent version on Melpa or Elpa does not even have `org-babel-shell-names` or any other bash processing. Not sure if it is licensing or omission. I am now using _ob-shell.el_ from org Git repo rather then the _ob-sh.el_ shipped on Elpa/Melpa and that provides all that I need. Still interesting why Elpa/Melpa is shipping an older version.

Comment: I'm using Org-mode version 8.3beta (release_8.3beta-902-gac1298 @ /path/to/orgmode.git)!??

Comment: See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/83356, particularly the comment of Eric Schulte (main author of Babel). I'm not sure I fully understand it, though.

Comment: On versions: My version is Org-mode version 8.2.10 (8.2.10-35-g19a7d6-elpa ) which is the latest on Elpa. I like using packages from Elpa/Melpa for simplicity - which in this case clearly does not have the _ob-shell.el_ but rather _ob-sh.el_ that I suppose you have in your beta. The link you sent confirms my above comments where it talks about the rename from "sh" to "shell". I suppose will wait for Elpa to move to 8.3 version (although it all already works for me with the manually loaded _ob-shell.el_ )

Comment: Pay attention, though, when loading ob-shell: you end up mixing Org versions, what could lead to troubles. OTOH, if you don't see anything wrong, there's no reason not doing it...

Comment: Yeah, everything behaves normal so far. But you are right , I agree, not recommending mixing versions. Looking for 8.3 to be out of beta. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you are using straight/ use-package try this:-

```
(use-package ob-shell
  :straight nil
  :after org
  :config
  (setq org-babel-default-header-args:sh '((:results . "output")))
  (setq org-babel-default-header-args:shell '((:results . "output"))))
```